# Spring Security ACL with EhCache 3

Tags: spring-security, ehcache, ehcache-3, spring-security-acl

I tried to update to EhCache 3, but noticed that my AclConfig for spring-security-acl no longer works. The reason is `EhCacheBasedAclCache` still uses `import net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache`. EhCache moved to `org.ehcache` since version 3 and thus this no longer works. Is there a replacement class provided by spring for EhCache 3 or would i need to implement my own Acl Cache?
This is the code, which no longer works:

```
@Bean
public EhCacheBasedAclCache aclCache() {
    return new EhCacheBasedAclCache(aclEhCacheFactoryBean().getObject(),
            permissionGrantingStrategy(), aclAuthorizationStrategy());
}
```

Comment: Found any solution?

Comment: After seeing no traction here i abandoned the update. I will maybe try again later this year and if i find a solution i will answer this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added bounty to your question because I'm also looking for a more authoritative answer.
Here's a solution that works, but there could be a better approach & cache settings could be tuned specifically for acl.

1. The `JdbcMutableAclService` accepts any `AclCache` implementation, not just `EhCacheBasedAclCache`. Immediately available implementation is `SpringCacheBasedAclCache`. You could also implement your own.
2. Enable ehcache3 in your project with Spring Cache as abstraction. In Spring Boot this is as simple as using `@EnableCaching` (not `@EnableCache`) annotation. Then add `@Autowired CacheManager cacheManager` in your bean configuration class.
3. Update your ehcache3.xml with entry for aclCache
   *note - key is `Serializable` because Spring acl inserts cache entries keyed on both Long and ObjectIdentity :)*

```
    <cache alias="aclCache">
        <key-type>java.io.Serializable</key-type>
        <value-type>org.springframework.security.acls.model.MutableAcl</value-type>
        <expiry>
            <ttl unit="seconds">3600</ttl>
        </expiry>
        <resources>
            <heap unit="entries">2000</heap>
            <offheap unit="MB">10</offheap>
        </resources>
    </cache>
```

4. Replace your `EhCacheBasedAclCache` bean with `SpringCacheBasedAclCache` like so:

```
    @Bean
    public AclCache aclCache() {
        return new SpringCacheBasedAclCache(
                cacheManager.getCache("aclCache"), 
                permissionGrantingStrategy(), 
                aclAuthorizationStrategy());        
    }
```

5. Use `aclCache()` in `JdbcMutableAclService` constructor

Comment: We have now moved to EhCache 3 and this is exactly what we are doing!