# How to config Spring Security ACL

Tags: spring, spring-boot, security, acl

I follow the guide on [Spring Security ACL with EhCache 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56157479/spring-security-acl-with-ehcache-3/76458343?noredirect=1#comment134815879_76458343) to using EhCache 3 in the config, but I have circular references issue within the config. please help. this is the config file that has the issue:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity (prePostEnabled = true)
public class AclConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration{

    @Autowired
    MethodSecurityExpressionHandler defaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler;

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        return defaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler;
    }

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    CacheManager cacheManager;

    @Bean
    public MethodSecurityExpressionHandler
    defaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler() {
        DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler
                = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        AclPermissionEvaluator permissionEvaluator
                = new AclPermissionEvaluator(aclService());
        expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(permissionEvaluator);
        return expressionHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcMutableAclService aclService() {
        return new JdbcMutableAclService(
                dataSource, lookupStrategy(), aclCache());
    }

    @Bean
    public AclAuthorizationStrategy aclAuthorizationStrategy() {
        return new AclAuthorizationStrategyImpl(
                new SimpleGrantedAuthority("WRITE"));
    }

    @Bean
    public PermissionGrantingStrategy permissionGrantingStrategy() {
        return new DefaultPermissionGrantingStrategy(
                new ConsoleAuditLogger());
    }

    @Bean
    public AclCache aclCache() {
        return new SpringCacheBasedAclCache(
                cacheManager.getCache("aclCache"),
                permissionGrantingStrategy(),
                aclAuthorizationStrategy());
    }

    @Bean
    public LookupStrategy lookupStrategy() {
        return new BasicLookupStrategy(
                dataSource,
                aclCache(),
                aclAuthorizationStrategy(),
                new ConsoleAuditLogger()
        );
    }

}
```

Below is the error

```
Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

   projectingArgumentResolverBeanPostProcessor defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/web/config/ProjectingArgumentResolverRegistrar.class]
      ↓
   metaDataSourceAdvisor
┌─────┐
|  aclConfig
└─────┘


Action:

Relying upon circular references is discouraged and they are prohibited by default. Update your application to remove the dependency cycle between beans. As a last resort, it may be possible to break the cycle automatically by setting spring.main.allow-circular-references to true.


Process finished with exit code 1
```